# Use material-ui in react-native

Tags: react-native, material-ui

- I am developing an app(**react-native**) that requires material design implementation.
- While surfing through the internet I found :

  1) [Material ui](https://material-ui.com/) (For React components)

So,as a beginner  I want to ask whether I can use **material-ui** for **`react-native`** or not!

Answer (score 2):

Material-UI is specially designed for React JS which will output or render the components in the form of HTML tags in the browser. As the browser supports HTML and CSS, Material UI works perfectly fine but in the case of Native Apps, it follows a different syntax and implementations hence you cant use Material UI on native apps.

However, few components are available to be used within react native apps.
https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui

> https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md

Comment: It should be noted that the above library seems to be unmaintained as of 2019